# How can I automate trigger deployment to Mongo Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, trigger, deployment, mongodb-atlas

I have a couple of triggers on a Mongo Atlas cluster that I want to deploy to a number of databases on a different cluster.

Is there any way to do this automatically, through a script or something similar? Or do I really need to connect and do it by hand for each and every database?